# Uncaught Error: useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component (In react js )

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

**I removed some code so it will become easier to read**

> But everthing is imported correctly and working correctly but i can't figure out this error
> **i got this error but i saw a tutorial and even reactRouter site have same way but it's not working with my code**

**I wan't to change Route when Enter key is pressed in keyboard**

> This is the app.js file

```
function App() {
       
  return (
    <div>
        <div key="navbar" className="navbar">
            <Navbar />
        </div>
        <div key="search-box" className="search-box">
            <SearchBar carddata={cards}/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <Cards key="cards" carddata={cards} />
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> This is the file where All Routes are happening when useNavigate changes the Route it should Open the Route That i wan't to open ('/SearchResult')

```
const Cards = ({ carddata: cardComponent }) => {
  return (
//This is the file that should open when the useNavigate change Route to "/SearchResult"
          <Route path="/SearchResult" element={<SearchResPage />}></Route>
        </Routes>

        <div className="right-section">
          <RightCard cardData={cardComponent} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
export default Cards;
```

**This is the file that will change the Route using useNavigate and the file i wan't to open is searchResPage (code will be below this Code)**

```
import {  useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const SearchBar = ({ carddata}) => {
  const navigate=useNavigate();

  //it's the function called onKeyDown
function searchResult(e) {
    
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      if (e.target.value === "") return;
        //it for changing the Route 
          navigate('/SearchResult')

        //it for filtering the result passed from props and the show them
        carddata.filter((result) => {
          if (`${result.heading}`.toLowerCase().match(e.target.value)) {
              console.log(result)
            }  
      });
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex">
      <input onKeyDown={searchResult} type="text" ></input>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchBar;
```

> or is there any other way to change the Route when enter key is pressed without refreshing the page i was able to find out this option i don't know why it's not working

Comment: Based on that error message, it sounds like this component is not somewhere inside the `Router` component, which is required.

Comment: it's inside Router and it has path='/SearchResult'

Comment: It's a bit hard to say without seeing the structure of your app and where the `SearchBar` component is compared to the `Router`. Can you post enough code to show that? This error message is pretty clear, though.

Comment: ok i will do that

Comment: Where do you import searchBar component ?

Comment: Have you declared the `Route`?
`<Route path='/SearchResult' element={SomeComponent}/>`

Comment: @Amirhossein  search bar is in app js but i wan't to change Route to **'/SearchResult'**  search bar will change the route when i click enter and cards.js will then Route to the path='/SearchResult'                                                          that's what is want to achieve

Comment: Can you post the entire higherarchy of components leading to the first route-parent which renders the searchbar?

Comment: these are the file i removed some code that file will become easier to read please  : @no_modules

Answer (score 0):

The error means you are trying to use hook `useNavigate` outside of a `Router`.
The most common is in `react-router-dom` package as `BrowserRouter`, then you have `Routes` and `Route` component.

Should be something like this (the Router could be here in App or another file, like in the  `index.js`):

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

import ExamplePage from "./components/ExamplePage";
import SearchBar from "./components/SearchBar";

function App () {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>        {/* <--- the component needed, Router */}
        <SearchBar /> {/* <--- your component  with the useNavigate inside the Router */}
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/my-page" element={<ExamplePage />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
};

export default App;
```

Then your component should work.

Comment: brother what i want is when i press enter a function will run in **searchBar File** then it try to change Route based on the condition which file it try to open is inside the  
                                                                                                                                  
<Router><Routes><Route path='/SearchField element={searchResPage}></Route></Routes></Router>  **But this Route is in different file**  why it is in different file because there are many **Route so it will take those Route place and load at  those place**

Comment: @SHERAWATLOKESH, yes, the SearchResPage is inside the Router, but your Searchbar **isn't**. You're invoking useNavigate  inside SearchBar which is **outside** the Router.
It's not enough for the **SearchResPage** to be there. every hook from `react-router-dom` **must** be inside the `Router` as well.
I edited the post so it can be better understood.

Answer (score 0):

i made it work what you have to do is remove `BrowserRoute or Router` from the file and paste it to main parent file eg.`app.js` file

```
add Router to app.js or  parent file add cover the code In Router
```

```
<div>
 <Router>  <---------//just Like this---
          <div key="navbar" className="navbar"><Navbar /></div>
              <div key="search-box" className="search-box">
                <SearchBar carddata={cards} onChangeSet={setSearchData}/>
              </div>
              <div>
                 <Cards key="cards" carddata={cards} SearchingDataResult={searchData}/>
              </div>
                     
      </Router> <---------here----
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).